# vertica sql: running sum for 1 hour

Tags: sql, vertica

I know there are a lot of forum questions on running totals, but somehow I don't quite know how to apply to my example. So appreciate if somebody can help.

I am trying to calculating the hourly running total of 'speed' partition by 'ID'. How can I proceed on this? I am using vertica database. Thank you!

```
DATETIME,ID,speed
05-12-15 0:15,1,40
05-12-15 0:30,1,61
05-12-15 0:45,1,66
05-12-15 1:00,1,48
05-12-15 1:15,1,66
05-12-15 1:30,1,50
05-12-15 1:45,1,47
05-12-15 2:00,1,70
05-12-15 2:15,1,42
05-12-15 2:30,1,58
05-12-15 2:45,1,74
05-12-15 3:00,1,43
05-12-15 3:15,1,57
05-12-15 3:30,1,69
05-12-15 3:45,1,52
05-12-15 4:00,1,43
05-12-15 0:15,2,48
05-12-15 0:30,2,73
05-12-15 0:45,2,41
05-12-15 1:00,2,56
05-12-15 1:15,2,65
05-12-15 1:30,2,76
05-12-15 1:45,2,66
05-12-15 2:00,2,49
05-12-15 2:15,2,75
05-12-15 2:30,2,67
05-12-15 2:45,2,76
05-12-15 3:00,2,47
05-12-15 3:15,2,53
05-12-15 3:30,2,76
05-12-15 3:45,2,63
05-12-15 4:00,2,56
```

EDIT:
Final outcome should be something like this:

[image]

Comment: Start with SELECT EXTRACT(HOUR FROM DATETIME), ID SUM(speed) and a GROUP BY on EXTRACT(HOUR FROM DATETIME), ID

Comment: sorry, I just updated my post~ I don't wish to aggregate the table, it should remain the same number of rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to partition by id and use `range between '1 hour' preceding and current row`. `RANGE` works on the value in the `ORDER BY` to limit the window frame.

```
select datetime, 
       id, 
       speed, 
       sum(speed) over (partition by id 
                        order by datetime desc
                        RANGE BETWEEN '1 hour' PRECEDING 
                              AND CURRENT ROW) sum_speed_1hour
from mytable
order by id, datetime
```

Also, notice the datetime desc, which based on your examples is what you are looking for.

Comment: appreciate it lots @woot!

Answer (score 0):

> you can try this:

```
select
    TIME_SLICE(datetime, 1, 'HOUR'),
    sum(speed)
from mytable
group by TIME_SLICE(datetime, 1, 'HOUR')
order by TIME_SLICE(datetime, 1, 'HOUR')
```